# How do i sort items in response of SoapUI according to my preference

Tags: rest, api, testing, functional-programming, soapui

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/haKoI.jpg)

I want to sort the "name" section according to the logic "numbers first, then capital letters and then small letters". How do I accomplish that?

Comment: Please add the text response. Also provide some context about your use case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More information would be nice. On first sight though, it looks like you are looking for XQuery assertions. This will not order or modify the response, but it will transform the response in the assertion to match it against a set with an order that you control.

When to use it? When you are not sure in which order you get entities, and you want to match those dynamically sorted items to a fixed set.

An example can be found here: http://readyapi.smartbear.com/structure/assertions/property/xpath/xquery/example

I'll try and compose a sample project with some examples as a reference.

One thing though: don't stop at the example from the SoapUI site. You can go nuts. Everything you can retrieve with XPath, you can use in XQuery.

Example: assume that there is an xml as from [this source](http://www.service-architecture.com/articles/object-oriented-databases/xml_file_for_complex_data.html) (useful stuff here as well, mind you) - XQuery under example

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="catalog.xsl" type="text/xsl"?>
<!DOCTYPE catalog SYSTEM "catalog.dtd">
<catalog>
   <product description="Cardigan Sweater" product_image="cardigan.jpg">
      <catalog_item gender="Men's">
         <item_number>QWZ5671</item_number>
         <price>39.95</price>
         <size description="Medium">
             <color_swatch image="red_cardigan.jpg">Red</color_swatch>
             <color_swatch image="burgundy_cardigan.jpg">Burgundy</color_swatch>
         </size>
         <size description="Large">
             <color_swatch image="red_cardigan.jpg">Red</color_swatch>
             <color_swatch image="burgundy_cardigan.jpg">Burgundy</color_swatch>
         </size>
     </catalog_item>
     <catalog_item gender="Women's">
         <item_number>RRX9856</item_number>
         <price>42.50</price>
         <size description="Small">
             <color_swatch image="red_cardigan.jpg">Red</color_swatch>
             <color_swatch image="navy_cardigan.jpg">Navy</color_swatch>
             <color_swatch image="burgundy_cardigan.jpg">Burgundy</color_swatch>
         </size>
         <size description="Medium">
             <color_swatch image="red_cardigan.jpg">Red</color_swatch>
             <color_swatch image="navy_cardigan.jpg">Navy</color_swatch>
             <color_swatch image="burgundy_cardigan.jpg">Burgundy</color_swatch>
             <color_swatch image="black_cardigan.jpg">Black</color_swatch>
         </size>
         <size description="Large">
             <color_swatch image="navy_cardigan.jpg">Navy</color_swatch>
             <color_swatch image="black_cardigan.jpg">Black</color_swatch>
         </size>
         <size description="Extra Large">
             <color_swatch image="burgundy_cardigan.jpg">Burgundy</color_swatch>
             <color_swatch image="black_cardigan.jpg">Black</color_swatch>
         </size>
     </catalog_item>
 </product>
</catalog>
```

Now assume you don't know in which order these things arrive. You do know that the test data itself is quite stable. This could imply that the item numbers retrieved by this query will very likely be the same ones. For our sake, let's say you want test for the price to be the expected price.

Then you have two options:
1. Create a separate XPath for each item you expect
2. Create a verifiable query with XQuery (you can find that under assertions)

The XQuery example:

```
<results>
    {
        for $item in //catalog/product/catalog_item
        let $id := $item/item_number
        let $price := $item/price
        order by $id
        return
            <price itemId='{data($id)}'>{data($price)}</price>
    }
</results>
```

The result of this query would be this:

```
<results>
     <price itemId='QWZ5671'>39.95</price>
     <price itemId='RRX9856'>42.50</price>
 </results>
```

With the line `for $item in //catalog/product/catalog_item` I tell the XQuery to iterate over all elements with that address. The variable 
`$item` can be used further down the line. This might seem futile here, but in more complex cases modularity is your friend. Further down the line I define more variables. You don't have to, but I like to be more verbose rather than to not see what I did later on (I'm a functional tester). To assign variables, you use the statement `let $id := $item/item_number`. As you can see, I reuse the parent over which I iterate as I dig deeper into the XML.

When performing some functions, then we need to define the functions with the 'boundaries' `{` and `}`. Note: The function to retrieve actual data is `{data(variable with path or path here)}`.

In essence you wouldn't even need to include the item ids. You can order on a value without including it in your returned output. I personally like it to have them in my set to verify later discrepancies.

As for the numbers first, then capital, then small cap, I don't know if you're using the right tool for the job. I'm sure it is possible. But given you can trust SoapUI to sort the XQuery the same way each time because it will use the same XQuery engine each time, I can't imagine that it is of importance to actually have the numbers first, then the large cap, then the small cap. The goal would be to verify a set that is sorted consistently when taken from the response.

Essentially, to calibrate the assertion, you would feed an example XML of expected output with a mock. Then, in the assertion configuration screen, you can choose to get the expected output from the response xml with your designed Xquery.

If it is truly of the essence that the sort is as you described, then please elaborate more.

Sources for XQuery:

- https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/XQuery/Searching,Paging_and_Sorting
  https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xquery_intro.asp
  https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp

Bulky, still incomplete, but might be a solution to the core of your problem: verifying a consistently sorted response with an assertion native to SoapUI.